# How to install TideSDK from TideSDK-1.2.1 package?

Tags: tidesdk

I've downloaded package TideSDK-1.2.1.RC1-0be9cd89-windows-7-x86-64.zip from tidesdk.org. Installer was found in tidesdk\sdk\win32\1.2.0.RC4\installer. This installer doesn't work: "Installation failed. The installer could not determine the application path."

What's wrong with it? Is it the only (right) way to install TideSDK? No docs on topic were found in resources and links on tidesdk.org.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you picked up an artefact from our Continuous Integration System from some point in time in development. We will eventually expose a Nightly Build site for developmental releases. That said, we will do this once the 1.3.0-beta is ready so we can properly support you with developmental artefacts.

Please use the legacy 1.2.0.RC4 in the interim that can be downloaded from front page of tidesdk.org until TideSDK 1.3.0-beta is available (which will be along very soon). This will serve your development needs in short term as we continue the work to get the beta prepared.

A new 'Getting Started Guide' will be up later today for the legacy 1.2.0.RC4 as there have been many requests for this help.

We appreciate how much attention our project is getting and have been working hard as a team to produce great documentation. Despite this, our efforts were primarily targeted on the API documentation at the outset. We experienced a surge of interest prior to getting the new guides in place. Our apologies to anyone new that has experienced any difficulty getting started. We appreciate your patience while we fill these gaps.

The new documentation is being prepared in anticipation of the 1.3.0 release so that we have great API docs, guides, and example apps when the time arrives. It is targeted for the end of September. We hope to also have our Tide Builder app available at that time to provide a nice app to help create, run and package your apps. There will also be an enhanced tidebuilder CLI since a tool with a UI will be strictly an option. For those that appreciate minimalism, this will get you going with no more than the SDK and a text editor.

Comment: Regarding your flag, can you have both accounts share one e-mail? If not, you'll need to contact team@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/) first.

Once that's done, you can install the package : Help menu > Install Sepcific Titanium SDK.